# Kotlin Intent: Wont resolve package name

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin

I'm trying to start a Kotlin class from a Kotlin class in another package with the following code:

```
    if (tickets!!) {
        icTicket.setOnClickListener {

            val request = Intent(this, com.ticketmainia.ticketmainia.tickets.TicketsMain)
            request.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            applicationContext.startActivity(request)
        }
```

and Android Studio says:

> Unresolved reference for "com.ticketmainia"

The Kotlin Class itself is located in the package:

> com.ticketmainia.ticketmainia.json.

Has this anything to do with this?

This is the TicketsMain:

```
class TicketsMain : AppCompatActivity(), IVolley {
    override fun onResponse(response: String) {

        Toast.makeText(this@TicketsMain, "" + response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

    }
```

Comment: have you tried with `TicketsMain::class.java` ?

Comment: can you post the package name in the TicketsMain class?

Comment: @Ashish: yes, it marks me the TicketsMain as red and suggests me to insert the full package name

Comment: @Sunny : I'm not sure what you want me to do

Comment: I think you should delete an import state outside class. Because it showing package name here is because its already present there in import.@LosKayos

Comment: @LosKayos I just want to check the package of the class.

Comment: @Sunny look at my edit :) // my fault, it isn't a java class, it's a ktolin class I'm trying to start here

Comment: @LosKayos I am just asking for the package like this **package cc.echonet.activities;** is written on top of file.

Comment: @sunny: yes it is, in both files (target and start from file)